# Put crossdomain.xml into icecast2 webroot

Tags: permissions, flash, icecast

I'm trying to put a crossdomain.xml file inside icecast2 web root to be able to access by the flash player

```
http://mydomain.com:8000/crossdomain.xml
```

I'm frustrated now. Tried everything possible but cannot access file from a outside browser.
Getting this error

**The file you requested could not be found**

Changed file permissions and everything. but no luck. 
Even I renamed existing css file just to see if I can access it outside. I can see original file but after renaming I cant even access that css file.

What is going on. Permission issue? Please help. I cant stream OGG without that flash policy file.

My Icecast Version is 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On debian and its derivatives, this includes Ubuntu, the Icecast webroot is in:

```
  /usr/share/icecast2/web
```

Just putting the file there should make things work.

Comment: Just a quick note: When you've put the file where it's supposed to be, make sure that IceCast2 is able to serve files too. `<fileserver>1</fileserver>` in your IceCast2 configuration XML.